# Method overload in Android Titanium Module

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

Is it possible to do method overloading for Titanium modules? specifically for Android

I have these sample codes:

**Android**

```
@Kroll.method
public void logout(KrollFunction callback)
{
    Log.d(LCAT, "start logout");
    final Activity activity = this.getActivity();
    final Branch instance = Branch.getInstance(activity);

    instance.logout();

    callback.call(getKrollObject(), new HashMap());
}

@Kroll.method
public void logout()
{
    Log.d(LCAT, "start logout");
    final Activity activity = this.getActivity();
    final Branch instance = Branch.getInstance(activity);

    instance.logout();
}
```

**Javascript**

This doesn't work

```
$.onlogoutClicked = function() {
    Ti.API.info("inside onlogoutClicked");
    branch.logout(function () {
        alert('Logout Session');
    });
}
```

This works!

```
$.onlogoutClicked = function() {
    Ti.API.info("inside onlogoutClicked");
    branch.logout();
    alert('Logout Session');
}
```

**Note that I implemented an overload method for logout wherein you can optionally pass a callback method or not**

So I was wondering how do you overload Java class methods for Titanium?

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem? Facing the same issue at the moment

Comment: sorry, I haven't.